# Refresh/Update gnus Summary Buffer

Tags: gnus

The gnus Summary Buffer can be refreshed/updated to [show](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995930/580010) new articles with `/ N`.

How can the buffer be refreshed/updated to remove messages deleted with `B DEL`? These remain after issuing `B DEL` and `/ N`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is `M-g` I think. It will get ride of the deleted articles. This shortcut is bound to `gnus-summary-rescan-group`.

Basically it will exit the group, ask for new articles then select the group again.